# How to replace wrong file with correct one in 60 ec2 instances with same folder structures?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have 60 ec2 instances which share the same folder structure are similar to one another but not completely identical. The incorrect file was uploaded to all 60 instances and I was wondering what would be the best way to replace that file with the correct one? The file is named the same and is placed in the same location throughout all the instances. Am new to using AWS in general so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you show an example of what you've tried? How about this: https://superuser.com/a/338798/191864

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't want to use something like ansible, have access to the servers and want to use just bash you could do something like:
Put all your IP addresses of your servers into a file, one on each line - like so:

*IpAddresses.txt*

```
10.20.15.1
10.20.15.44
10.20.15.65
```

Then create a script:

*myscript.sh*

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line; do
    ssh -i path_to_key.pem ec2-user@$line 'sudo rm -rf /path_to_directory | command 2 | command 3'
done < IpAddresses.txt
```

Maybe you could do something like the above to first remove the directories you don't want and then do an scp to copy the correct file in.

Depends on the commands you need to correct the problem, but this is an option.

Note, I haven't tested this command exactly - so you may need to correct/test a bit.

Refs:
https://www.shellhacks.com/ssh-execute-remote-command-script-linux/

Answer (score 0):

If your EC2 instances have the correct [IAM permissions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/sysman-configuring-access-role.html), you could use the Simple Systems Manager (SSM) console, using the [`Run Command`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/execute-remote-commands.html) service. Click 'Run a command', then select `AWS-RunShellScript` from the list of command documents. In the text box you can specify a shell command to run, and below that you can choose the set of instances you want to run the command on.

This is the recommended way to update and administer large fleets of instances such as you have.